# Why does Spring Boot BatchAutoConfiguration prevent repositories from saving during integration test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-test

In my spring boot project, having parent spring-cloud-starter-parent Bristxon-M4, I have encountered a problem in my integration tests when adding this to a test class:

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration({BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

My problem is that I do not fully understand the startup sequence and in which order the configurations are loaded - at least I suspect that is my problem.

The behaviour I am observing is that when I try to save two different `@Entity` objects which have a `@ManyToOne(optional=false)` relation in the `@Before` method of another test, it fails with this message:

> Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.

My setup is as follows:

Code snippets from the application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CollectionBatchJobConfiguration ...

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJms
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class MyServiceApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     SpringApplication.run(MyServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Code snippets from the test packages:

```
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({BatchAutoConfiguration.class, CollectionBatchJobConfiguration.class, RepositoryTestConfiguration.class})
public class CollectionBatchJobTestConfiguration
{
  @Autowired
  @Bean
  public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils()
  {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
  }
...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(CollectionBatchJobTestConfiguration.class)
public class CollectionBatchJobIT 
{
       @Autowired
       private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
...

@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
    FlywayAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RepositoryTestConfiguration ...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyServiceApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyRestServiceIT
{
  @Autowired
  private EntityARepository entityARepo;
  @Autowired
  private EntityBRepository entityBRepo;

  @Before
  public void before()
  {
    EntityA a = new EntityA();
    a = entityARepo.save(a);
    EntityB b = new EntityB(a);
    entityBRepo.save(b); // This line fails with org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException 
  }
 ...
```

I am running MariaDB externally and use Flyway to clean and migrate schema with repo tables and tables for Spring Batch. The service works as expected under manuel test and initially when running both the MyRestServiceIT and the CollectionBatchJobIT with the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` class set to MyServiceApplication ran and passed all test.

But in my attempt to optimise test execution time and to be more in line with what appears to be Spring Boot best practice for testing, I am slimming down the loaded test configurations and using the new `@ImportAutoConfiguration` together with custom TestConfiguration classes instead of using the main SpringBootApplication class MyServiceApplication.
I have succeeded in improving my other integration tests but after finishing the CollectionBatchJobIT then the MyRestServiceIT failed in the `@Before` block with this hibernate error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation :  
...  
Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation
```

The stacktrace shows that the save invocation is in fact from the `@Before` block. 
When debugging, the save operation of entityA shows the missing ID and the database does not contain the expected row.

**So to sum up**: After adding the BatchAutoConfiguration to one test, another test fails because it can no longer persist entities to the underlying database.

Can anyone body explain what happens or how I can figure out the reason behind it?

Btw. if the BatchAutoConfiguration is omitted from the `@ImportAutoConfiguration` line the CollectionBatchJobIT fails because nothing gets committed to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may stem from the fact that the tests which are using `MyServiceApplication` for configuration automatically include all your test configuration classes due to component scanning being enabled by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. This is most likely not what you want.

One way to exclude these is to replace `@SpringBootApplication` with the following under the assumption that your test configuration classes are named accordingly:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
                                        pattern = ".*TestConfiguration.*"))
```

Comment: Using this approach makes both tests run and printing loaded beans before and after shows that the CollectionBatchJobTestConfig is no longer loaded. 
`
Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).stream().forEach(name -> System.out.println(name))
`
It is still unclear what exactly ruined the test but I assume the import ordering of configs to be the reason.
I would like to avoid this componentscan in the main app and instead have it overridden in the test class though. 
This is acceptable for now.